# How can I count the exact word?

Tags: python, count

For example I have a code like this

```
string = "abito to doto moto" 
print(string.count("to"))
```

I just want the result to be 1, but it always count "to" in the other three as well

Answer (score 2):

You might use regular expression (`re` module) following way:

```
import re
string = "abito to doto moto"
occurences = len(re.findall(r'\bto\b',string))
print(occurences)
```

Output:

```
1
```

Explanation:
`\b` has special meaning in 1st argument of `re.findall` namely word boundary - meaning that there needs to be start of string or punctuation (including space) before `to` and end of string or or punctuation (including space) after `to`.
So my code would give 1 also for string equal to `abito to, doto moto` or `abito to: doto moto` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I have ingored the first and last occurences of "to". you can change the condition in for loop as per your need.

```
li = list(string.split(" ")) 
count = 0;
for i in range(1,len(li)-1):
    if li[i]== "to":
        count= count + 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

`string.count(" to ")` works only if there is no special characters after `"to"`

here's some examples:

```py
    >>> string = 'abito to doto moto to.'
    >>> string.count("to")
    5
    >>> string.count(" to ")
    1
    >>> string.split().count("to")
    1
    >>> string.split(" ").count("to")
    2
    >>> import re
    >>> sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r'\b%s\b' % re.escape("to"), string))
    2
```

Edit: Thank @Grzegorz Krug for suggest edit, this will give you result of **2** (since my `string` is different from @Jess example) when using regex:

`how_many = len(re.findall('\Wto\W', string)) # '\W' is to avoid word symbols a-zA-Z and _`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add blanks to this string 'to' -> ' to ', which i don't recommend. Becouse it look like you want to find words 'to', and adding space may fails if string starts from 'to'

```
string = "abito to doto moto" 
words = string.split()
print(words.count("to"))
```

Comment: This is nice and works if words are always separated by space (not commas or dots).